# React-Router out of sync with window.location?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having trouble getting client-side routing to work properly (with react-router-dom@5.2.0)

I have an `<Application>` component which returns:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/:filter/:id">
      <Something...>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
      <SomethingElse...>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Whenever I navigate to `[localhost]/rating/good`, things work as expected: the proper route is matched (ie. `"/:filter/:id"`) and the `<Something>` component is rendered.

I have a button which clears what I call filters; whenever I click on it:

- I update the URL with `useHistory().push('/')`
  The change is immediately observed
- I update of my AppState, which triggers an update of my `<Application>` component, which in turn means `<BrowserRouter>` and `<Route>` are updated.

And that's when I observe something I didn't expect:

The same route as before (ie. `path="/:filter/:id"`) is matched and the `<Something>` component is rendered -- despite the current URL pathname being `"/"`.

**Is this the expected behavior?**
**If yes, what is react-router using to match routes if not the current window.location?**

Now I've got it to work (I think) by updating `<Application>` with:
`const location = { ...useLocation(), pathname: window.location.pathname }`

And passing that `location` object as such:
`<Switch location={location}>`

But it feels like I'm doing something wrong and that it should have worked without me fiddling with the location object.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: can you show your route configuration inside the switch

Comment: The only 2 routes are <Route path="/:filter/:id"> and <Route path="/">, I have no other configuration

Comment: I think you need to pass the 'exact' prop to the Route component